# CoreLocation AttributeError

Tags: python, objective-c, core-location

I am trying to find my Mac's current location using the following python script. It is using the python objective-C bridge and it works sometimes. However sometimes I am getting the following AttributeError and I'm unsure what I should do to fix the error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# encoding: utf-8

import CoreLocation
manager = CoreLocation.CLLocationManager.alloc().init()
manager.delegate()
manager.startUpdatingLocation()
coord = manager.location().coordinate()
lat, lon = coord.latitude, coord.longitude
print lat, lon
```

Following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/SimpleCoreServices.py", line 11, in <module>
    coord = manager.location().coordinate()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'coordinate'
```

[Apple's developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW72) isn't helping me out since my Objective-C isn't that strong.

Comment: So, when `manager.location()` can't get the location, what does it return? I'll bet it returns `None`.

Comment: You are correct `manager.location()` does return None. I need to create a try block to get CoreLocation to research for a location when None is returned. Thank you kindall. (still new to python).

Comment: You can just do `loc = manager.location()` and then `if loc is None` (search for a location) `else coord = loc.coordinate()` or something similar, without needing exception handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait until `locationd` prompts for location access. Then allow python to use location services. I added a wait block to your code:

```
import CoreLocation
from time import sleep

manager = CoreLocation.CLLocationManager.alloc().init()
manager.delegate()
manager.startUpdatingLocation()
while CoreLocation.CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != 3 or manager.location() is None:
    sleep(.1)
coord = manager.location().coordinate()
lat, lon = coord.latitude, coord.longitude
print (lat, lon)
```

The prompt will be shown while the loop is waiting for `authorizationStatus` and getting a value in `location`. Sometimes it takes about 30 seconds to show the dialog:

[image: Location access prompt]

If the user accepts the access by choosing "Allow", the value of `authorizationStatus` becomes 3. After that, the loop will be continued to wait until a location value obtained.

Unfortunately, controlling the access via the Security and Privacy section in System Preferences will be impossible sometimes. Because of disappearing the python row in Location Services list, you cannot check or uncheck it. Also, the `tccutil` shell command cannot control this.

If you accidentally chose the "Don't Allow" button, it can be reset with [these](https://superuser.com/q/526183/541820) instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the script when Hamid Rouhani did it. Geo-location are not detected.I solve it like this I go to

> System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> allow geolocation services for python.

And instantly python returns geolocation to me.