# Using CoreLocation from python on OS X

Tags: python, macos, core-location, cllocationmanager

I want to get my Mac's current location using CoreLocation APIs from Python. I know that I could get them invoking some command line executables or something similar, but I am interested in using CoreLocation's own Python bindings.

So far I could create a class which should act as a delegate and create an instance of `CLLocationManager`. Calling `startUpdatingLocation()` shows OS X's location permission requester, and the location icon appears on the menu bar, but I never get any of my delegate methods called. `authorizationStatus()` returns `3`, which is `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized`.

What's wrong?

```
"""
Core Location Python test
"""

import Cocoa
import CoreLocation

locaitonSearchFinished = False

class CLTestDelegate(Cocoa.NSObject):
    def locationManager_didUpdateLocations_(self, manager, locations):
        print u"New Location: %s" % locations
        locaitonSearchFinished = True

    def locationManager_didFailWithError_(self, manager, error):
        print u"Error updating location: %s" % error
        locaitonSearchFinished = True

    def locationManager_didChangeAuthorizationStatus_(self, manager, status):
        print u"Status: %s" % status

delegate = CLTestDelegate.alloc().init()
locationManager = CoreLocation.CLLocationManager.alloc().init()
locationManager.setDelegate_(delegate)
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

print locationManager
print delegate
print CoreLocation.CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

while locaitonSearchFinished == False:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I just added the print statement 
 print locationManager.location() 
to your code to get results.

With help from : [CoreLocation AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755998/corelocation-attributeerror)